# Accomplishing Client-side Work During Page Initialization

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In order to complete the initialization of an entry-point page, I need some data which can only be obtained through a third-party via client-side JavaScript. Hence, I need some sort of temporary page to be served which will run the JavaScript code before the target page gets rendered. How can I accomplish this?

My Server-side code, ***MyPage.aspx.vb*** may look something like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
    ...
    ...
    // Read data from DB which gets written via client-side 
    // JavaScript interacting with web service
End Sub
```

Comment: check my answer out, and let me know if it had any problem.

Comment: So your page loads. There are some js calls which initialize the data in page. They make calls to db to fetch them. Why don't you show some spin wait image until all such calls are complete? Something similar to a splash screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two different pages your target page which here is **MyPage.aspx**, and as you yourself have mentioned, a temp page like `Temp.aspx`. Use a flag to check if your client-side task is done, in the session scope. like:

Session["AjaxCallIsDone"]

in your your **MyPage Page_Load** method, check if it is true:

```
If(Session["AjaxCallIsDone"] == null ||
   !(Boolean)Session["AjaxCallIsDone"])
    Response.Redirect ("Temp.aspx");
```

Ok then, now it goes to the temp page if your ajax call hasn't been done yet.

using jQuery or raw javascript, create your ajax call in the temp page:

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "third-party-server-url",
    type: "POST",//or may be GET
    data: yourdata
});
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //your client-side task is done
});
```

create a `Handler` or `Generic Handler` to let client inform the server about the ajax call and to set the `AjaxCallIsDone` flag, do this in your handler method;

```
Session["AjaxCallIsDone"] = true;
```

then in your request callback create another ajax call to call that `Handler`, then in handlerRequest callback function do your redirect like this:

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "third-party-server-url",
    type: "POST",//or may be GET
    data: yourdata
});
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //your client-side task is done
    var handlerRequest = $.ajax({
        url: "your-handler-url",
        type: "GET"
    });
    handlerRequest.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        document.location="MyPage.aspx";
    });
});
```

and now all is done.

Comment: For the most part, I've implemented your technique. The only clumsy part is the flag un/setting: if the process gets interrupted or I want to request the page with a different query string, I have to deal with a session flag which has already been set to true. (Maybe this is only an issue in debug mode?)

Answer (score 0):

Some more specifics / example code of what you got so far would be nice.

If you are using jQuery then you could use the getScript method...

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( data ); // Data returned
  console.log( textStatus ); // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
  //now do what you need to do
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Hope that helps.

Comment: I added a bit of an example. How are you answering the question

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery AJAX instead of **Temp.aspx**,

> **Step 1.** Get the data from third-party via client-side JavaScript.
>
> **Step 2.** Using jQuery AJAX, get the data from from your DB which gets written via client-side & render it.

Comment: I need the data on server-side.

Comment: If the data from **Step 1** is required in Server Side, than make another AJAX call to save it, before **Step 2**. Basically, my point is not to use Temp.aspx (overhead server calls), instead use the lighter AJAX calls.

Comment: actually it is more of an asp.net question and less js. the problem here is he wants to do something, before the main page is loaded.

Comment: Instead of JS AJAX,  **ASP.NET update panel** can be implemented. My point is in similar situation I would have used partial post backs, not multiple redirects using Temp.aspx.